# Batching of queries is not allowed by J2EE compliance

Tags: jdbc, db2

I am trying to run a stand alone Java application which executes a batch of `Select` queries with `PreparedStatement` ( by using `addBatch() & executeBatch()` functions of `PreparedStatement` ) against DB2 V 9.7.

I am getting this error message at `executeBatch()`,

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.lh: [ibm][db2][jcc][105][10840] Batching of queries is not allowed by J2EE compliance.
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.c(gg.java:2566)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.b(gg.java:2536)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.executeBatch(gg.java:1421)
    at
```

Anybody know about this error? Nothing shows up on SO or Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems pretty self-explanatory to me.

I've only ever seen `INSERT`/`UPDATE` used with addBatch.

Given that [executeBatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) returns just `int[]` it seems obvious that it wouldn't be of much use for `SELECT` queries.

Comment: Its dumb from my side , I just put SELECT queries as place holders because those are harmless while I was waiting for UPDATE & INSERT sqls :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible if you move your logic for multiple dynamic SQL statements into a Stored Procedure.  You can then issue one JDBC call to the stored procedure.